# ¿Se puede cubrir todo el alto de la ventana con un código jquery y javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hay paginas donde al cargarlas el *header* o la cabecera ocupan todo el alto y ancho de la ventana y sé que eso se hace con código JavaScript. Para eso tengo el siguiente código en jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#banner").css({"height":$(window).height() + "px"})
});
```

ese código hace que al entrar en la página, ésta ocupe ancho y alto, pero al encoger la página no es responsivo. He buscado por diversos medios y he codificado de distintas maneras para encontrar la forma de crear el código adecuado, pero no logro encontrar la solución.

Quiero saber cómo resolver este problema tanto con JavaScript puro, como con la librería jQuery, y saber la diferencia de ambas soluciones.

Answer (score 4):

Tal y como lo tienes ahora mismo, el código sólo se ejecuta cuando se carga la página y por eso cuando cambias el tamaño de la ventana, no hay ningún cambio en la visualización de tu banner. Lo que estás buscando es el evento [`onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize).

La idea sería llamar a tu código cuando la página se cargue y también cuando se redimensione la ventana. Eso lo puedes hacer así con jQuery:

```
function redimensionaBanner() {
    $("#banner").css({"height":$(window).height() + "px"})
}

// redimensionamos el banner cuando se cargue la pagina
$(document).ready(function(){
    redimensionaBanner();
});

// ... y cuando se redimensione la ventana
$(window).on("resize", function() {
    redimensionaBanner();
}
```

Con JavaScript puro tampoco habría mucha diferencia, en lugar de asociar el evento con jQuery, lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
window.onresize = redimensionaBanner;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ha funcionado ala perfección y tal como dices no había ningún cambio en la visualización y tenia que refrescar la pantalla pero con el código restante funciona muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta que te ha dado Álvaro es correcta. Voy a añadir sólo un par de sugerencias. Si usas jQuery y ES6 puedes cambiar la altura del elemento que necesites con un código más breve:

```
$(window).on('resize', => $('#elemento').height($(window).height))
```

Esta línea de código aprovecha que el método .height() de jQuery funciona a la vez como getter y setter. Si haces `console.log($('#elemento').height())` verás que devuelve la altura actual del elemento, mientras que si haces `$('#elemento').height('480px')` estás cambiando la altura.